# PHP 5.6 cannot find libssl1.0.2 after update

Tags: php, openssl, libssl

I've a server with Ubuntu server with ISPConfig. I've installed and configured additional php 5.6 version. After updating ubuntu, I get the following error when I try to run php --version:

```
./php --version
./php: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After the update the version of openssl is 1.1, I was unable to find how to install openssl 1.0.2. Any ideas how to fix the problem?